# Complexity of checking whether a proposition is an intuitionistic tautology given that it's a classical one

Tags: complexity-theory

What is known about the complexity of the promise problem "determine whether a propositional formula is a tautology in intuitionistic logic, given that it is a tautology in classical logic"?

Does it matter whether you have access to a proof that the proposition you're asked to validate is a classical tautology?

---

I think the most efficient known algorithms for determining whether a formula in classical propositional calculus is a tautology are exponential in the size of the formula (measured in the number of connectives). I don't know the best known upper bounds, but here's a quick sketch of exponential time algorithms for classical and intuitionistic logic.

$A \to (B \lor A)$ is a tautology. This can be done by considering all subsets of the variables, so $\varepsilon, A, B, AB$, and seeing if the formula is true in each of the worlds described by the subsets. I think this establishes an upper bound of "exponential in the number of connectives".

For determining whether a formula is an intuitionistic tautology, we can use the refinement logic algorithm described [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kreitz/teaching/CS486/notes-11.pdf).

A subset of the rules concerning $\land$ and $\lor$ are reproduced below. The line of inference separates the previous state of the proof algorithm from the new state.

Left-and

$$ \frac{H, A \land B, H' \vdash G}{\triangleright\;\;\;\;H, A, B, H' \vdash G} $$

Right-and

$$ \frac{H \vdash A \land B}{\triangleright\;\;\;\;H \vdash A \text{ and } H\vdash B} $$

Left-or

$$ \frac{H, A \lor B, H' \vdash G}{\triangleright\;\;\;\;H, A, H' \vdash G \text{ and } H, B, H' \vdash G} $$

Right-or

$$ \frac{H \vdash A \lor B}{\triangleright\;\;\;\;H \vdash A \text{ or } H \vdash B} $$

This gives us an exponential time algorithm for checking whether a propositional formula is a tautology in intuitionistic logic, since all of the inference rules are entirely syntax-directed and some of the rules produce 2 branches which both need to be checked. The rules can be thought of as marching through a formula by pattern matching on connectives and recursing.

It isn't obvious to me one way or the other whether the fact that something is a classical tautology could be used to "prune" possible options when performing a split ... or to write more aggressive decomposition rules involving multiple connectives, but that is the motivation behind the question.